# IPEndPointCollection missing under System.Net

Tags: c#, p2p, system.net

(If this is a dumb question I apologies for it, but I'm new to C# language).
I'm creating a P2P system in C# with Visual Studio 2019 and I need the IPEndPointCollection class, but I don't find it under System.Net, only IPEndPoint appears.
I've searched the internet but I wasn't able to find an answer.
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this a .NET Core project? `IPEndPointCollection` is in .NET Framework, but isn't part of Core. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: I checked and it's a .NET standard 2.0.
I wanted to create a class containing the name of the peer and the collection of its endpoints

Comment: Would a `List<IPEndPoint>` work?

Comment: Yes, I think. But I was wondering why in tutorials and even in the microsoft documentation it seems there should be no problem. So I was asking to know if I did something wrong

Comment: It sounds like the issue is that your project is .NET Standard. If your project was for .NET Framework, `IPEndPointCollection` would be available to you.

Comment: Thank you @itsme86 for the clarification and for the help.
Gonna see if a List will fullfill my needs, otherwise I will change to .NET Framework.